# Drawing a unique figure including a curve with tikz in a specific way

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, bezier

I am interested in drawing the following figure with tikz

[image]

I (think) I know how to do this with Bézier curves using \draw with filling, but I want the top curve to be an exact graph of a function that depends on a parameter, like f(x)=cos(kx) or f(x)=exp(kx), where I can adjust the parameter k to later animate my tikz figure.
My problem is that I do not know how to use \draw to connect everything together, along with plotting the top curve using an actual function along with the green filling underneath.
I would appreciate all help on this.

Comment: What you tried so far?  At known function you can draw it by `\draw plot (\x,<your function>)`. Of course, for plot you can define function domain and number of samples too. See TikZ & PGF manual, *22.5 Plotting a Function*, page 344

Comment: @Zarko thank you. I don't actually know how to combine plotting a specific function for the top curve along with the draw command to connect the lines that make up the three straight-line sides. I also would not know how to make the green filling in this hybrid approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the points and the `plot` in the same `\draw` command.

Something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

% example of a function with a parameter \k
\tikzset{declare function={f(\x,\k)=0.5*cos(2*\x r)+\k;}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,3) |- (4,0) -- (4,3);
\draw[fill=green!20] plot[samples=101,domain=0:4] (\x,{f(\x,2)}) -- (4,0) -| cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,3) |- (4,0) -- (4,3);
\foreach[count=\ii]\i in {green,orange,yellow}
  \draw[fill=\i!20] plot[samples=101,domain=0:4] (\x,{f(\x,2.5-0.5*\ii)}) -- (4,0) -| cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: First figure]

[image: Second figure]

Comment: thank you very much for the great answer

Comment: @TeXAndSuch, you're welcome!!